# How to reset class variable to default value 0?

Tags: java, android

If anybody can tell me different way to do this, I would appreciate. How to reset class variable to 0, or default value? I use class variable cause I don't know another way to do this. After my game ends I place result in class variable, cause I have two rounds of my game, and after first round ends I add the result, and class variable is good for this cause even after I restart my game method it still holds my previous result. After second round is over I add that result to previous result and then close the activity and set text result as text to a button. But when I click New game, that button still holds that text, cause class variable still holds it. How to reset that class variable when I go on New game?

Here's my game code, some of it (100 points are start amount, and it gets lower in game progress):

```
public class Asocijacije extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

int brojPoenaAsocijacije = 100;
    public static int brojPoenaUkupno;
```

Then I skip here a lot of code and here's where I add points. brojPoenaAsocijacije are points earned in that round:

```
brojPoenaUkupno = brojPoenaUkupno + brojPoenaAsocijacije;
```

Here's my main activity where I set points from my class variable to a button (where I added comment):

```
public class Izbor extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Asocijacije poeni = new Asocijacije();

    Button toploHladno, asocijacije, cigle, spojnice, nazad, poeniTH, poeniAso, poeniCigle, poeniSpojnice;
    TextView naslov;
    public boolean music;
    MediaPlayer buttonClicks, buttonBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.izbor);

        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        music = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox", true);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }



    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        buttonClicks = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
        buttonBack = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button31);

        Typeface naslovType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Lobster.ttf");
        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        naslov = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIzborNaslov);
        toploHladno = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzbor1);
        asocijacije = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzbor2);
        cigle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzbor3);
        spojnice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzbor4);
        nazad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzborNazad);
        poeniTH = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPoeniTH);
        poeniAso = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPoeniAso);
        poeniCigle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPoeniCigle);
        poeniSpojnice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPoeniSpojnice);
        naslov.setTypeface(naslovType);
        toploHladno.setTypeface(dugmad);
        asocijacije.setTypeface(dugmad);
        cigle.setTypeface(dugmad);
        spojnice.setTypeface(dugmad);
        nazad.setTypeface(dugmad);
        poeniAso.setTypeface(dugmad);

        toploHladno.setOnClickListener(this);
        asocijacije.setOnClickListener(this);
        cigle.setOnClickListener(this);
        spojnice.setOnClickListener(this);
        nazad.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart(); 
        poeniAso.setText("" + poeni.brojPoenaUkupno); //I do it here
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bIzbor1:
            if(music == true){
                buttonClicks.start();
                    }
            startActivity(new Intent("rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.GAME"));
            break;
        case R.id.bIzbor2:
            if(music == true){
                buttonClicks.start();
                    }
            startActivity(new Intent("rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno.ASOCIJACIJE"));
            break;
        case R.id.bIzbor3:
            if(music == true){
                buttonClicks.start();
                    }

            break;
        case R.id.bIzbor4:
            if(music == true){
                buttonClicks.start();
                    }

            break;
        case R.id.bIzborNazad:
            if(music == true){
                buttonBack.start();
                    }
            poeniAso.setText("");
            finish();
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your variable names are not really helping...

Comment: Do you use the same button when starting a new game, as when advancing to the next round? If that is the case, you should use a counter, and reset both the counter and the result once the counter reaches a certain value.

Comment: No, not the same. I use Handler to reload my game activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I don't find the piece of code where you start the new game, I can only say:

```
Asocijacije.brojPoenaUkupno = 0;
```

Comment: I thought I should try something like that, make new object from Asocijacije class, and then call pre made method that sets the brojPoenaUkupno to 0, but now from your code, I can see that's a little bit overkill. :) I'll try what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Probably want to reset your state when you close the in-game activity.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Asocijacije.brojPoenaUkupno = 0;
    //whatever other things need to be reset.
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example in code how would you do get method for this? Just to try that way too. I tried now to setup setters and getters and I get 0 in my points box.

Comment: i jsut realized that Izbor and Asocijacije are different classes, better to just reset your state in onDestroy().
If New Game is in Asocijacije, then just reset the game state in Izbor. If it's in whatever calls Asocijacije, then you'll have to reset the game state in Asocijacije.

Comment: New game in not in asocijacije. It's in it's own class. From there I go to Izbor and from there I go to Asocijacije.